# SSRS Default Start/End Dates Return a period of specific dates

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters, expression, default

I'm trying to write an expression in SSRS:

If today's **DAY** is <= 15th day, return pay period previous month 16th to last day of month 
If today's **DAY** is >= 16th day, return current month day 1st to 15th

This is the expression I have now but its not working:

Start Date:

```
=IIF(DAY(TODAY) <= 15, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-Day(Today), Today), DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 16-Day(Today), Today)))),
IIF(DAY(TODAY) >= 16, dateadd("m",0,dateserial(YEAR(Today),MONTH(Today),1)
```

End Date:

```
=IIF(DAY(TODAY) <= 15, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, DateSerial(Year(Date.Now), Month(Date.Now), 1)),
IIF(DAY(TODAY) >= 16, dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,datepart(dd,getdate()),15),getdate())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to do something similar in the past week...

```
--StartDate, if current day is more than 16, set to 1, else 16
=iif(DatePart("d",Today) >= 16,  DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today), "1").AddMonths(-1), DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today),"16").AddMonths(-1))

--EndDate, if current day is more than 16 set to 15, else month end
=iif(DatePart("d",Today) >= 16,  DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today), "15").AddMonths(-1), DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today),"1").AddDays(-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following expressions

StartDate:

```
=
Iif ( Day(Today())>15
, DateAdd( "d", -Day(Today())+1, Today())
, DateAdd("d", -Day(Today())+16, DATEADD("m", -1,Today()))
)
```

EndDate:

```
=
Iif ( Day(Parameters!DateParam.Value)>15
, DateAdd("d", -Day(Today())+15 , Today())
, DateAdd("d", -Day( Today()) ,  Today())
)
```